# weak reference in ios9 and ios8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

[Problem soluted!Just want to know why there is such a difference in ios8 and ios9]  I was making a register view controller these days and face with some problem about weak reference.

and below is some part of the code(swift)

problem come when I use an iphone6 ios8.1
it crashed.  And then I noticed that the weak reference is not proper here. But the code runs well in my ios9 iphone6s. I ran this code on an iphone6 ios8 simulator, app crashed. So I think there is some thing different in processing weak reference in ios8 and ios9, But who can explain why..?

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    weak var verifyTextField: UITextField?
    override func viewdidload() {
       //....
       verifyTextField = newTextField();
       view.addSubview(verifyTextField!);
    }
    func newTextField() -> UITextField {
        let ntf = UITextField();
        //do some settings to ntf;
        return ntf;
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Never** force unwrap](https://i.imgflip.com/utfq7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You set your new `UITextField` instance to the `weak var verifyTextField` but before you add it as a subview (which increments the retain count) it is deallocated (the count is 0 since the var is weak) so `verifyTextField!` crashes, the crash you're getting is most likely the famous

> Unexpectedly found `nil` while unwrapping an Optional

It's easy to fix it

1. Don't use a `weak var`
2. Don't force unwrap (use `if let` instead)

The code should be as follows:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    var verifyTextField: UITextField? //should not be weak
    override func viewdidload() {
       //....
       verifyTextField = newTextField()
       if let verifyTextField = verifyTextField {
          view.addSubview(verifyTextField!)
       }
    }
    func newTextField() -> UITextField {
        let ntf = UITextField()
        //do some settings to ntf
        return ntf
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah.. I've found this solution but just want to know why there is such a difference in ios8 and ios9. because when in ios9, my code runs just well.

Comment: and thank you,  I exactly get your point that when no strong reference point to an object, it will be released.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your object is deallocated instantly after initialization because you don't store any strong reference for it.

Try this code:

```
override func viewdidload() {
   //....
   let verifyTextField = newTextField();
   view.addSubview(verifyTextField);
   self.verifyTextField = verifyTextField;
}
```

Also no need to use `weak` reference here, because verifyTextField doesn't have reference to your VC, so you won't get a retain cycle.